# Given any odd sided square following this pattern, algorithmically create its matching list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, algebra

### The Pattern

You are given only the side length of a square:

- The side length is **ALWAYS = ODD**.
- The middle of the square's value **ALWAYS = 0**.
- Every other value = **distance from the center of the square**.

Write a program that generalizes this algorithm and creates a list representation of the input square by outputting a List of Lists

### Example Output

```py
"""
if input = 1    
Matching square:        0         =>  List Equivalent = [[0]]

if input = 3
Matching square:      1 1 1       =>  List Equivalent = [[1, 1, 1],
                      1 0 1                              [1, 0, 1],
                      1 1 1                               [1, 1, 1]]

if input = 5
Matching square:    2 2 2 2 2     =>  List Equivalent = [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                    2 1 1 1 2                            [2, 1, 1, 1, 2], 
                    2 1 0 1 2                            [2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
                    2 1 1 1 2                            [2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                    2 2 2 2 2                            [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]

if input = 7
Matching square:  3 3 3 3 3 3 3   =>  List Equivalent = [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                  3 2 2 2 2 2 3                          [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
                  3 2 1 1 1 2 3                          [3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
                  3 2 1 0 1 2 3                          [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
                  3 2 1 1 1 2 3                          [3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3],
                  3 2 2 2 2 2 3                          [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
                  3 3 3 3 3 3 3                          [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]]

"""
```

I'm tryin a solution that I will post that splits the square unevenly about 0 like so:

```
side = 5                                       _ _ _ _ _ _
Matching square:    2 2 2 2 2     Split square: 2 1 0 1 2
                    2 1 1 1 2                   2 1 1 1 2
                    2 1 0 1 2                   2 2 2 2 2        
                    2 1 1 1 2                           
                    2 2 2 2 2
```

And figure out how to generate each row based on its distance from the top row etc

### Question

Any existing solutions to this kind of pattern / problem that I'm trying to solve? I do not know what to search

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What would a program look like that generalizes this algorithm and creates a list representation of the input square by outputting a List of Lists. Someones already answered though

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. "How can I write code to solve this problem? I don't know what to search for" is not an actionable question. Start by *trying* to write your own code, and then figure out a clear explanation of *why* you are unable to solve the problem yourself. What went wrong with your attempt? What things would you need to be able to do, in order to solve the problem with your approach?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have been trying myself, on paper, I cannot get past a simple 2 level for loop. I literally do not know how to approach this problem. And as per the answer by the helpful user, my train of thought was completely wrong. I came here seeking guidance.

Comment: "I cannot get past a simple 2 level for loop." Where is that code? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel apologies, yes my question needs to be reformatted for sure I can see that, but I wasn't asking for someone to write the code for me, just whether there is an existing solution I could be directed to or what to search, and whether my approach is logical. Please see my Answer as I have figured it out now, I just made a simple mistake for a very, very long time on this problem regarding coordinate positions starting at 0 -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in a much simpler way

```
square_size = 11
centre_x = (square_size - 1) // 2
centre_y = (square_size - 1) // 2

matrix = []
for x in range(square_size):
    row = []
    for y in range(square_size):
        x_dif = abs(x - centre_x)
        y_dif = abs(y - centre_y)
        value = max(x_dif, y_dif)
        row.append(value)
    matrix.append(row)
```

Comment: This is much better. I was trying to solve it this way. You can also remove the `- 1` and just write `square_size // 2`.

Answer (score 1):

One relatively easy but not elegant way to do it is to spiral the matrix from the outside to the inside and decrement the value for each new cycle. As follows:

```py
def create_matrix(n): 
   curr = n // 2 
   matrix = [[0]*n for _ in range(n)] 
    
   counter = 0 
   N = n*n 
   left, right, top, bottom = 0, n-1, 0, n-1 
   while True: 
       # top 
       for i in range(left, right+1): 
           matrix[top][i] = curr 
           counter += 1 
       top += 1 
       if counter >= N: 
           break 
       # right 
       for i in range(top, bottom+1): 
           matrix[i][right] = curr 
           counter += 1 
       right -= 1 
       if counter >= N: 
           break 
       # bottom 
       for i in range(left, right+1): 
           matrix[bottom][i] = curr 
           counter += 1 
       bottom -= 1 
       if counter >= N: 
           break 
       # left 
       for i in range(top, bottom+1): 
           matrix[i][left] = curr 
           counter += 1 
       left += 1 
       if counter >= N: 
           break 
       curr -= 1 
   return matrix
```

A quick test:

```
In [2]: create_matrix(11)                                                                                              
Out[2]: 
[[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
 [5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5],
 [5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5],
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5],
 [5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5],
 [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]]

In [3]: create_matrix(5)                                                                                               
Out[3]: 
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 0, 1, 2],
 [2, 1, 1, 1, 2],
 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```